# Adding an if statement to django-cms template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I'm probably missing something very obvious but can't see anything in the documentation. I have a carousel with a  and each  will hold an image. However I've added 6  but I want to add an if statement so if an Image has not been added you don't see a blank space, where there is no content inside the .

Here is what i've tried so far:

```
{% if "Carousel 1" %}
<li>
{% placeholder "Carousel 1" %}
</li>
{% endif %}
```

Attempt 2:

```
{% placeholder "Carousel 1" as cara1 %}

{% if cara1 %}
  <li>

{{ cara1 }} 

   </li>
 {% endif %}
```

Not sure if there is something differnt i need to be doing for the django-cms template tags?

Any help would be much appreciated. Docs here - http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/advanced/templatetags.html#placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be rude, but your approach is way, way off :)

Placeholders hold Content Plugins. Content Plugins are responsible for how they render their contents.

My advice would be to create or find a carousel content type plugin. This plugin will hold multiple images or "CarouselImage" model instances that you can iterate over, and also specify a template with which to render itself.

In this template resides the conditional statement you're wanting to check for. Placeholders are just that - places held for content plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and you are not being rude. I've never looked at it that way. django-cms is new to me, so still trying to work out the best way to do things like this. I'll create a model for the gallery Images and then create a plugin to reference that model.

My only issue is, last time i created a plugin i could i only select one post from that model. Is that because of the way i built the plugin? Or can you only select one instance of the model per plugin? Hope that last bit made sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it does. What you'd want to do in that case is structure your plugin one of two ways. Either you need a ManyToMany field for your images, or you need to reference them as inlines on a "Gallery" model. I would recommend the latter, since you may want to provide Alt text, or links to other pages from those instances, which you wouldn't be able to do with an M2M.

Comment: Brill thanks really helps. Will update the question as soon as i've found the best solutions. Thanks again Brandon.